# Como formatar números decimais utilizando Fluent API no Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, fluent-api

Como criar uma formatação com a precisão **10,4** (4 casas decimais) para salvar dados decimais no SQL Server? Essa descrição de formato vai dentro do modelBuilder, porém, não tenho encontrado algum código já definido para fazer esta formatação.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use o `HasPrecision`:

```
public class EFDbContext : DbContext
{
   protected override void OnModelCreating(System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   {
       modelBuilder.Entity<Class>()
        .Property(object => object.property)
        .HasPrecision(10, 4);

       base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
   }
}
```

[Veja mais detalhes sobre configuração de mapeamentos de propriedades usando Fluent API na documentação.](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-property-mappings-using-fluent-api.aspx)

Comment: Obrigado, George. A solução é esta mesmo. Porém, aparece um erro, identificado exatamente na palavra reservada ".HasPrecision".O seguinte erro, é: "Erro: CS1061 - ‘PropertyBuilder<double>’ não contém uma definição para "HasPrecision" e não foi possível encontrar nenhum método de extensão "HasPrecision" que aceite um primeiro argumento do tipo ‘PropertyBuilder<double>’
". Saberia dizer do que se trata?

Comment: @VictorMoraes Mude o seu campo para o tipo decimal pra usar precisão. Ele está como double.

Comment: Já mudei lá no domínio e continua mostrando o erro.

Answer (score 2):

Se precisar configurar uma propriedade do tipo decimal, use:

```html
        modelBuilder.Entity<Class>(entity =>
{
            entity.Property(e => e.PropertyName)
            .HasColumnType("decimal(10,2)");
});
```